# Website homepage is not a child of root

Tags: wagtail

I have a wagtail installation with one site. The site has a homepage and all works fine on the surface, but i have messed up the tree structure somehow.

The Root page shows no child pages. If I try to create a page under the root i get

```
ValidationError at /cms/pages/add/website/indexpage/1/
{'path': ['Page with this Path already exists.']}
```

If I try to 'move' the home page to be a child of the root I get no error but the home page still doesn't appear in the list of the roots children

If I try to 'move' a different page to be a child of the root I get the following error

```
IntegrityError at /cms/pages/115/move/1/confirm/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "wagtailcore_page_path_key"
DETAIL:  Key (path)=(00010001) already exists.
```

Trying to loaddata to a fresh database from a dumpdata gives me the following error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update on table "website_highlightspage" violates foreign key constraint "website_highlightspage_page_id_0f12432c_fk_wagtailcore_page_id"
DETAIL:  Key (page_id)=(55) is not present in table "wagtailcore_page".
```

It looks like I've permanently orphaned my homepage although I'm not exactly sure how I've done this.

I'd like to know if there is anyway to fix up this issue, or export current pages to a fresh instance before this problem becomes critical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `./manage.py fixtree` - it can fix certain types of tree corruption (and give more diagnostics on the problems it can't fix automatically). I'd suggest taking a backup of the database first, as a precaution.

Comment: Yes. This is the correct fix. The num_child column for the root page incorrectly was set to 0, which was causing the tree structure problems. Updating it manually with sql also fixes the problem. 

The problem with the loaddata command is a separate issue.